# Form taking values from previous forms and making it non-editable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, zod

when I add values for the postal address and I get switched to the shipping address form for some reason the values from the postal address are transferred to the shipping address and are non-editable.
It just takes the value from the postal address form to the shipping address form and makes it fixed, I can't put new values and i can't delete the value

```
const AddClient = () => {
    const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
    const [USERID, setUSERID] = useState('')
    const { toast } = useToast()
    const router = useRouter()

    const postalSchema = z.object({
        houseNumber: z.string().min(2, {
            message: "House number must be at least 2 characters long",
        },).max(25, {
            message: "House number must be at most 25 characters long",
        },),
        type : z.string().default('postal'),
        streetLine1: z.string().min(10, {
            message: "Street line must be at least 10 characters long",
        },).max(125, {
            message: "Street line must be at most 125 characters long",
        },),
        streetLine2: z.string().min(10, {
            message: "Street line must be at least 10 characters long",
        },).max(125, {
            message: "Street line must be at most 125 characters long",
        },).optional(),
        city : z.string().min(2, {
            message: "City must be at least 2 characters long",
        },).max(25, {
            message: "City must be at most 25 characters long",
        },),
        country: z.string().min(2, {
            message: "Country must be at least 2 characters long",
        },).max(25, {
            message: "Country must be at most 25 characters long",
        },),
        postalCode: z.string().min(2, {
            message: "Postal code must be at least 2 characters long",
        },).max(25, {
            message: "Postal code must be at most 25 characters long",
        },),
        userID : z.string().default(USERID),
    })
    const shippingSchema = z.object({
        houseNumber: z.string().min(2, {
            message: "House number must be at least 2 characters long",
        },).max(25, {
            message: "House number must be at most 25 characters long",
        },),
        type : z.string().default('shipping'),
        streetLine1: z.string().min(10, {
            message: "Street line must be at least 10 characters long",
        },).max(125, {
            message: "Street line must be at most 125 characters long",
        },),
        streetLine2: z.string().min(10, {
            message: "Street line must be at least 10 characters long",
        },).max(125, {
            message: "Street line must be at most 125 characters long",
        },).optional(),
        city : z.string().min(2, {
            message: "City must be at least 2 characters long",
        },).max(25, {
            message: "City must be at most 25 characters long",
        },),
        country: z.string().min(2, {
            message: "Country must be at least 2 characters long",
        },).max(25, {
            message: "Country must be at most 25 characters long",
        },),
        postalCode: z.string().min(2, {
            message: "Postal code must be at least 2 characters long",
        },).max(25, {
            message: "Postal code must be at most 25 characters long",
        },),
        userID : z.string().default(USERID),
    })

  type TPostalData = z.infer<typeof postalSchema>;
  type TShippingData = z.infer<typeof shippingSchema>;

  const postalForm = useForm<TPostalData>({
  resolver: zodResolver(postalSchema),
  });

  const shippingForm = useForm<TShippingData>({
  resolver: zodResolver(shippingSchema),
  });

  const [buttonLoading, setButtonLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const nextStep = () => {
  setStep((prevStep) => prevStep + 1);
  };
    const prevStep = () => {
    setStep((prevStep) => prevStep - 1);
  };

    const onSubmitPostal = async (data: z.infer<typeof postalSchema>) => {
        setButtonLoading(true)
        const res = await fetch('/api/addresses/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        const json = await res.json()
        console.log(json)
        if (!res.ok) {
            toast({
                variant: "destructive",
                title: "Error",
                description: json.message,
            })
            setButtonLoading(false)

        }
        if (res.ok) {
            toast({
                title: "Success",
                description: json.message,
            })
            setButtonLoading(false)
            nextStep()
        }
    }

    const onSubmitShipping = async (data: z.infer<typeof shippingSchema>) => {
        setButtonLoading(true)
        const res = await fetch('/api/addresses/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        const json = await res.json()
        console.log(json)
        if (!res.ok) {
            toast({
                variant: "destructive",
                title: "Error",
                description: json.message,
            })
            setButtonLoading(false)

        }
        if (res.ok) {
            toast({
                title: "Success",
                description: json.message,
            })
        }
    }


    const renderStep = () => {
    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <>
            clientform
          </>
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <>
              <Form {...postalForm} >
            <form onSubmit={postalForm.handleSubmit(onSubmitPostal)}>
              <div className={"flex items-center border-b border-gray mb-4"}>
                <span className={"px-4 text-gray2 font-semibold text-xs pb-2"}>Details</span>
                <span className={"px-4 text-blue font-bold text-xs border-b-2 border-blue pb-2"}>Postal Address</span>
                  <span className={"px-4 text-gray2 font-semibold text-xs pb-2"}>Shipping Address</span>
            </div>

              <div className={"grid gap-4"}>
                  <FormField
                  control={postalForm.control}
                  name="houseNumber"
                  render={({field}) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>House Number</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input placeholder="Enter house number" {...field} />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={postalForm.control}
                    name="streetLine1"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>Street Line 1</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter street line 1" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={postalForm.control}
                    name="streetLine2"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>Street Line 2</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter street line 2" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={postalForm.control}
                    name="city"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>City</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter city" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={postalForm.control}
                    name="country"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>Country</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter country" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={postalForm.control}
                    name="postalCode"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>Postal Code</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter postal code" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

              </div>
            <div className='flex justify-between my-5'>
                <div>
                    <SheetClose asChild>
                        <Button className={"border border-danger text-danger bg-white py-2 rounded-md px-4 mx-1 font-medium text-xs"} type="button">Close</Button>
                    </SheetClose>
                    <Button disabled={buttonLoading} className='bg-blue text-white py-2 px-7 rounded-md mx-1 font-medium text-xs' type={"submit"}>Save</Button>
                </div>

            </div>
            </form>
              </Form>

          </>
        );
        case 3:
        return (
          <>
              <Form {...shippingForm} >
            <form onSubmit={shippingForm.handleSubmit(onSubmitShipping)}>
              <div className={"flex items-center border-b border-gray mb-4"}>
                <span className={"px-4 text-gray2 font-semibold text-xs pb-2"}>Details</span>
                <span className={"px-4 text-gray2 font-semibold text-xs pb-2"}>Postal Address</span>
                  <span className={"px-4 text-blue font-bold text-xs border-b-2 border-blue pb-2"}>Shipping Address</span>
            </div>

              <div className={"grid gap-4"}>
                  <FormField
                  control={shippingForm.control}
                  name="houseNumber"
                  render={({field}) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>House Number</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input placeholder="Enter house number" {...field} />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={shippingForm.control}
                    name="streetLine1"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>Street Line 1</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter street line 1" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={shippingForm.control}
                    name="streetLine2"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>Street Line 2</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter street line 2" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={shippingForm.control}
                    name="city"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>City</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter city" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={shippingForm.control}
                    name="country"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>Country</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter country" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

                    <FormField
                    control={shippingForm.control}
                    name="postalCode"
                    render={({field}) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel className={"text-gblue"}>Postal Code</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Enter postal code" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                    )}/>

              </div>
            <div className='flex justify-between my-5'>
                <div>
                    <SheetClose asChild>
                        <Button className={"border border-danger text-danger bg-white py-2 rounded-md px-4 mx-1 font-medium text-xs"} type="button">Close</Button>
                    </SheetClose>
                    <Button disabled={buttonLoading} className='bg-blue text-white py-2 px-7 rounded-md mx-1 font-medium text-xs' type="submit">Save</Button>
                </div>

            </div>
            </form>
              </Form>

          </>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

    return (
        <div>
                {renderStep()}
        </div>
    )
}
export default AddClient
```